# Problem while computing a lmer model connected with eval_f

Tags: r, error-handling, lme4

I am running the following model

```
library(lmerTest)
lmerTest::lmer(E ~ B + C + D + (1|A), df3)
```

on this dataset

```
    df3 = structure(list(A = c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57"), B = c(84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5), 
    C = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), D = c(73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
    72, 72, 72, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
    71, 71, 71, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
    73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 
    74, 74, 74), E = c(136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 
    136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 136.061064886813, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 91.138451650252, 
    91.138451650252, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 
    144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 144.422871899338, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 105.603501603159, 
    105.603501603159, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 
    128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 128.444375466774, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 57.1855792612815, 
    57.1855792612815)), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

but on my end I am getting as error

```
Error in eval_f(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

Comment: Is this your actual data?  There's no within-group variation on any of the variables.

Comment: just try the new I have updated my post with

Comment: There is still no within-group variation on any of the variables.  You can get rid of that error by putting `scale()` around `B`, `D` and `E` in your formula, but that brings up convergence warnings.  Those are likely because of the lack of within-group variation as they go away when you add some random noise to `E`.

Comment: Agreed. What's probably happening here is that the residual variance is going to zero, which messes things up.  You can do this with `nlme::lme()` or `glmmTMB::glmmTMB()`, both of which offer you the option of fixing the residual variance (to zero or something very small).